# The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert into a table variable, both from a View and from a Table, this is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
DECLARE @ResultCodes TABLE(ID_Audit INT,
                           AcctCode VARCHAR(3),
                           BidYear VARCHAR(4),
                           Num_Htls INT,
                           AuditStatus VARCHAR(50),
                           Account VARCHAR(3),
                           X INT, E INT, H INT, H_NLRA INT, N INT, Extra INT)

INSERT INTO @ResultCodes(ID_Audit, AcctCode, BidYear, Num_Htls, AuditStatus, Account, 
                         X, E, H, H_NLRA, N, Extra)
    SELECT 
        ID_Audit,
        AcctCode,
        BidYear,
        COUNT(ID_RFP),
        Audit_Status,
        Account 
    FROM 
        dbo.c_Audit_Rec_Status 
    WHERE 
        ID_Status_Audit = 105
    GROUP BY ID_Audit,AcctCode,BidYear,Audit_Status,Account
        UNION
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'H' AND Rate_Basis = 'LRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'H' AND Rate_Basis = 'NLRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        0
    FROM 
        tbl_FA_Results WHERE AuditDate3 IS NOT NULL         

        SELECT * FROM @ResultCodes
```

But I keep getting this error

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I've looked at this a hundred times if I've looked at it once and it seems like it should be working, can anyone see what I'm missing?

**EDIT**

This is the code I ended up with that works like a charm. Sometimes a second set of eyes is all it takes:

```
DECLARE @ResultCodes TABLE(ID_Audit INT,AcctCode VARCHAR(3),BidYear VARCHAR(4),Num_Htls INT,AuditStatus VARCHAR(50),Account VARCHAR(3),X INT,E INT,H INT,H_NLRA INT,N INT,Extra INT)
INSERT INTO @ResultCodes(ID_Audit,AcctCode,BidYear,Num_Htls,AuditStatus,Account,X,E,H,H_NLRA,N,Extra)
    SELECT 
        ID_Audit,
        AcctCode,
        BidYear,
        COUNT(c_Audit_Rec_Status.ID_RFP),
        Audit_Status,
        Account ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'H' AND Rate_Basis = 'LRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'H' AND Rate_Basis = 'NLRA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN ResultCode3 = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        0
    FROM 
        dbo.c_Audit_Rec_Status,
        tbl_FA_Results  
    WHERE 
        c_Audit_Rec_Status.ID_Status_Audit = 105 AND AuditDate3 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ID_Audit,AcctCode,BidYear,Audit_Status,Account
```

Comment: mysql? sql server? postgres? oracle?

Comment: You're selecting six columns after your insert statement and your insert has like twenty columns

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=The+select+list+for+the+INSERT+statement+contains+fewer+items+than+the+insert+list.&oq=The+select+list+for+the+INSERT+statement+contains+fewer+items+than+the+insert+list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ID_Audit,AcctCode,BidYear,Num_Htls,AuditStatus,Account,X,E,H,H_NLRA,N,Extra
> ```

is like 15 things.

> ```
>   ID_Audit,
>     AcctCode,
>     BidYear,
>     COUNT(ID_RFP),
>     Audit_Status,
>     Account
> ```

Is like 6 things. That won't work.

For more info :https://www.google.com/search?q=The+select+list+for+the+INSERT+statement+contains+fewer+items+than+the+insert+list.&oq=The+select+list+for+the+INSERT+statement+contains+fewer+items+than+the+insert+list.&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64l3.160j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at it all wrong, thinking the 2 select statements could work together to get me my 12 columns. Found the solution that I'll share just on the off chance someone else runs into something similar

Comment: I knew what the error was and what it meant, I just couldn't see where I was going wrong

Comment: @PsychoCoder from your question it really looks like you didn't do a search at all. If you do but can't figure it out anyway, it's much better to include the information you found and why you still can't figure it out.